# PHP - Grabbing vars from JSON array

Tags: php, json

I am using a PHP library (Abraham's OAUTH) as an app to connect to my twitter account and I am pulling down my own tweets from Twitter's API in an attempt to aesthetically display them on my on page.

I'm looping through them all with a foreach

```
<?php

foreach ($statuses as $key => $status) {
    echo '
    <blockquote class="twitter-tweet" data-lang="en"><p lang="und" dir="ltr">' . $status->text . '</p>
    ' . $status->name . ' (@' . $status->screen_name . ') <a href="https://twitter.com/' . $status->screen_name . '/status/' . $status->id_str . '">' . $status->created_at . '</a></blockquote><script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script><br>
    ';
}

?>
```

These are the from the var_dump and are the ones I am using

```
array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#3 (25) { ["created_at"]=> string(30) "Fri May 18 10:41:07 +0000 2018" ["id"]=> int(997426852204634112) ["id_str"]=> string(18) "997426852204634112" ["text"]=> string(27) "lol" ["name"]=> string(6) "Example" ["screen_name"]=> string(10) "Example_Name"
```

However I get returned:

> Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$name
>
> Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$screen_name

Why is this? I see name and screen_name in the var_dump so why is it not able to pick them up?

Comment: Edit: The whole var_dump: https://pastebin.com/sPMjjS03

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simply a notice, marking that the structure has no property.
You have several solutions:

1. Switch Notice error off (Not recommended) [Official php docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)
2. Check if the property exists and echo it only if it does. E.g.:

   ```
   isset($status->screen_name) ? $status->screen_name : '';
   ```
3. You can normalize data before output: just initialize the property with a default value if it doesn't exist:

   ```
    $status->screen_name = isset($status->screen_name) ? $status->screen_name : '';
   ```

**Update:**
In your case you try to access the wrong node:
`"screen_name"` is a node of the stdClass object `user`, which is a child of your status object. So, you need to call `$status->user->screen_name`.

Comment: Yeah, I don't understand why it has no property though - I see it in the var_dump with a value. I only have the error reporting on so I can figure out how to get name & screen_name to work as without them it can't really work

Comment: Switching notices off is only recommended for production usage, but never in developoment! You have to solve the cause of the error

Comment: I guess, you var_dump one element of the array, but the error occures with the subsequent one.

Comment: Can you provide var_dump of the whole $statuses array or clarify what data structure you described in the question? If now you show us the $status dump it obviously means that you try to access an array with a single stdClass element instead of the object itself

Comment: Updated the answer. According to your dump you access the wrong object.